# Python data manipulation: How to group by ID, then subset rows forward/back 1 month base on datatime conditions in each group?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want to subset data after groupby, and subset rows forward and backward 1 month by datatime conditions.

Here is the test dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain


df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID' : list(chain.from_iterable([['A'] * 365, ['B'] * 365, ['C'] * 365])),
        'Date' : pd.date_range(start = '2018-01-01', end = '2018-12-31').tolist() + pd.date_range(start = '2018-01-01', end = '2018-12-31').tolist() + pd.date_range(start = '2018-01-01', end = '2018-12-31').tolist(),
        'Value' : np.random.randn(365 * 3)
        })

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        'Initial_date' : pd.to_datetime(['2018-04-24', '2018-09-22', '2018-12-12'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')
        })


df = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how = 'left', left_on = 'ID', right_on = 'ID')
```

the output of test dataframe is:

```
  ID       Date  Value Initial_date
0  A 2018-01-01 -1.084   2018-04-24
1  A 2018-01-02  0.585   2018-04-24
2  A 2018-01-03  0.812   2018-04-24
3  A 2018-01-04 -1.115   2018-04-24
4  A 2018-01-05 -1.724   2018-04-24
```

So here is what I want to have:

For `A` user, his `initial date` is `2018-04-24`, so I want to have all rows from 1 month backward, which is `2018-03-24`, to 1 month forward, which is `2018-05-24`.
As well as `B` and `C` users.

The result should be the same as

```
df_a = df[(df['ID'] == 'A') & (df['Date'] > '2018-03-23') & (df['Date'] < '2018-05-25')]

df_b = df[(df['ID'] == 'B') & (df['Date'] > '2018-08-21') & (df['Date'] < '2018-10-23')]

df_c = df[(df['ID'] == 'C') & (df['Date'] > '2018-11-11') & (df['Date'] < '2018-12-31')]


df_result = pd.concat([df_a, df_b, df_c])
```

The `df_result.head()` is

```
   ID       Date  Value Initial_date
82  A 2018-03-24 -1.013   2018-04-24
83  A 2018-03-25 -0.023   2018-04-24
84  A 2018-03-26 -0.053   2018-04-24
85  A 2018-03-27 -1.091   2018-04-24
86  A 2018-03-28  1.839   2018-04-24
```

Note *1: For the marginal date, it is not necessarily included or excluded the exact date. For example, for `A`, from `2018-03-23` or `2018-03-24` does not matter for me.

Note *2: For `C` users, the forward date is less than 1 month since his `initial date` is on `2018-12-12`, so to the end of 2018 is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can try the following:

```
# set 1-month interval
delta = pd.DateOffset(months=1) 

# get the subset
df_result = df[df.Date.gt(df.Initial_date-delta) & df.Date.lt(df.Initial_date+delta)]
```

Comment: This solution is elegant and amazing! I think I will use this one on the original dataset. However, I am also trying to achieve the same result by using `groupby` since I am trying to understand the logic and usage of `groupby` of Python, hopefully, there will be answers using `groupby`.